# how to force update of a Serverless Angular SPA PWA hosted on Firebase and working with FireStore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

**Background:**

An Angular 8 PWA SPA. Uses Firebase Authentication. And Firestore as DB. (incl. Ionic 4)

All read and writes etc are done through the AngularFire npm.

There are cloud functions here and there that perform Business logic.

All packages are latest.

**The scenario:**

User on the move with open PWA version 3.1 in offline mode does an update to document of a type "SampleDoc" that are waiting for to be synced to the Firestore.

User hibernates his laptop for the weekend.

Over the weekend there is a SW update rolled out that changes the structure of the "SampleDoc" documents the DB is updated to the new format. A new version of PWA 4.0 is deployed.

User opens his laptop on Monday in the office with WiFi and the changes are applied to the DB corrupting the data.

**How to prevent that?**

I come from the classic Spring Boot based server world. Here is how we handle that:

Every HTTP request that goes to the server bares a header with a version of the API called example 
ApiVersion: 3.1.0

on the server there is a filter that checks the current version vs the incoming version and if it does not match rejects the request with an HTTP error code that the Web App knows that it needs to update itself. User notified that the changes can not be applied and an upp will update itself.

In the case of a Serverless Angular SPA PWA working directly with FireStore there is no way to add such filter.

what is the right way to address that in this tech stack?

One of the ideas is to subscribe to a doc that holds the current version of the DB/APP but will the notification about the update arrive **Before** the AngularFire will attempt to apply the changes?

Is there a way to prevent those changes from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do the same in Firestore, but then include the version number in the data you write. So in your document, include a version number field, and then check that in the server-side security rules of your database:

```
allow write: if (request.resource.data.clientVersion >= 5);
```

---

A slightly more complex version is to write this `clientVersion` value to a separate document, and combine that with the regular update in a batched write. You'd then use `getAfter()` in your security rules to validate the version:

```
allow write: if getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.clientVersion >= 5;
```

Comment: does this mean that I must contaminate every single document with a version? That I will have to maintain?
does security rules can check the version in incoming payload and remove it before actually storing the data?

Comment: those rules will just reject write but will not give any specific error code that will allow the app to deduce that it is outdated 
the write access denied can be matter of user permissions where changed by admin...

Comment: Correct on both counts. Another option is to forego direct writes through the database, and make them go through Cloud Functions. While a direct call to Cloud Functions wouldn't work while offline, you can have the client write a temporary document (with the version number), then have a Cloud Function validate the version, and update the final document(s).